# Loss data in MongoDB real-time application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io, real-time

I am developing an realtime application (**node, socket.io and mongoDB with Mongoose**) which receive data every 30 seconds. The data received is some metadata about the machine and 10 pressures.

I have a document per day that is preallocated when the day change (avoiding move data in the Database when documents grows saving data ), so I only have to do updates.

It data looks like:

```
{
 metadata: { .... }
 data: {
    "0":{
       "0":{
          "0":{
             "pressures" : {.....},
          },
          "30":{}
        },
        "1":{},
        "59":{}
      },
     "1":{},
     "23":{}
   }
 },
```

Without doing any Database operation in the server I receive the data from sensors every 30 seconds without problems and never lost the socket.io connection :

```
DATA 2016-09-30T16:02:00+02:00
DATA 2016-09-30T16:02:30+02:00
DATA 2016-09-30T16:03:00+02:00 
DATA 2016-09-30T16:03:30+02:00 
DATA 2016-09-30T16:04:00+02:00 
DATA 2016-09-30T16:04:30+02:00
```

but when I start doing updates (calling DataDay.findById(_id).exec()...) I lost half of the data and sometimes the socket.io connection i.e at (16:18h, 17:10h, 17:49h, 18:12h ..), It's like the server stops receiving socket information at intervals

```
DATA 2016-09-30T16:02:00+02:00
LOST
LOST
DATA 2016-09-30T16:03:30+02:00
DATA 2016-09-30T16:04:00+02:00
LOST
LOST
DATA 2016-09-30T16:05:30+02:00
LOST
```

I am using MONGODB with mongoose (with bluebird promises), but I am probably doing some blocking operation or something wrong, but I can't find out it.

The code treating the income data is:

```
socket.on('machine:data', function (data) {

  console.log('DATA ' + data.metada.date));

  var startAt = Date.now();                     // Only for testing
  dataYun = data;
  var _id = _createIdDataDay(dataYun._id);      // Synchronous

  DataDay.findById(_id).exec()                  // Asynchronous
    .then( _handleEntityNotFound )              // Synchronous
    .then( _createPreData )                     // Asynchronous
    .then( _saveUpdates )                       // Asynchronous
    .then( function () {
      console.log('insertData: ' + (Date.now() - startAt + ' ms'));
    })
    .catch( _handleError(data) );

  console.log('AFTER DE THE INSERT METHOD');
  console.log(data.data.pressures);
});
```

I have controlled how expensive were the operations and:

```
_createIdDataDay: 0 ms
_handleEntityNotFound: 1 ms
_createPreData 709 ms           // only is executed once a day 
_saveUpdates: 452 ms
insertData: 452 ms
```

This test has been done only with one machine sending data but the goal is receive data from 50 to 100 machines all of them sending data at the same time.

So from this test the conclusion is that every 30 seconds I have to update the database an the operation last more or less 452 ms.

So I don't understand where the problem is.

Is 452 ms too expensive for an update? 
Even so, I am not doing any operation more, and the next data comes in 30 seconds so it doesn't make sense loss data

I know that promises doesn't work well for multiple events (but I think this isn't the case), but not sure.

Can it be a problem with `socket.io`?

Or simply I am doing something that blocks the event loop but I can't see it.

Thanks

Comment: STOP SHOUTING AT US!

Comment: @ DrakaSAN stopped